# Please help clean up some "Litter" - [vsftpd] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, vote-to-close, clean-up

In a comment to the question "[User permission error with vsftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613150/user-permission-error-with-vsftp)", the OP remarks that "stackoverflow seems to be littered with [vsftpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsftpd) questions.".

I have used up my close votes for the day helping the OP with his problem, which is, in part, "stackoverflow seems to be littered with [vsftpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsftpd) questions.".

If interested, please help by marking these questions as off topic.

---

Edit: great work, but the tag in question was [vsftpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsftpd), not [vsftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsftp). 72 questions to go!

Comment: There are only 74 Qs in total. And scrolling down the page of Qs tagged vsftp, I don't see many downvotes. What is the issue - Tag used incorrectly?

Comment: No - questions are all or mostly off-topic. Leaving them unclosed encourages more users to ask more questions on the same off- topic.

Comment: 48 open questions need to be reviewed: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvsftpd%5D+closed%3A0

Comment: They all seem to be gone now...

Comment: @PatrickHofman was looking at [tag:vsftp] and not [tag:vsftpd]. Mea culpa.

Comment: Looks like the whole gang has been rounded up and locked in County.  Good job gents.  Most of them should meet the reaper^H^H^H^H^H^Hroomba soon.

Comment: [Seems it's done.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vsftpd]+closed%3Ano)

Comment: Looks like [there are still six more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvsftpd%5D+closed%3Ano), and they all appear to be new. I've put in my votes, but we need five votes to close a question...

Comment: @KevinBrown looks like it is 70+ more